# how to get unique values with excluding particular value in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I could able to get unique values from one sheet. but need to exclude few values while getting them from another sheet.

For example, Ive got below details from one sheet by using `=UNIQUE(Country!A1:A223)`. Now I need to exclude only India from this list . I tried with `=UNIQUE(filter(Country!A1:A223="India")` Which is not working.

India

China

US

UK

Australia

Singapore

How to exclude particular data from this list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To exclude India use:
=UNIQUE(filter(Country!A1:A223,Country!A1:A223<>"India"))
If you want to exclude a list of countries you can create a sheet named Country (the list of countries including duplicates), a sheet named Exempt (a list of countries to exempt from the Country sheet) and then enter this formula where you want the new country list to appear (this can be a new sheet. The formula assumes row one on the Country and Exempt sheets is a header row.

```
=unique(filter(Country!A2:A, isna(match(Country!A2:A, Exempt!A2:A, 0))))
```